# How to return an image saved in a database from a web api .net core?

Tags: database, image, api, asp.net-core, download

I have an image saved in my database.

```
public class FileData
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Oid { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return the file from my web api (.Net Core 3.1). I have tried this code. The image is returned, but appears damaged, cannot be seen.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetFileData(Guid id)
    {
        var fileData = await _context.FileData.FindAsync(id);
        if (fileData == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileData.Content);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
        return File(ms.ToArray(), contentType, fileData.FileName);
    }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I've also tried that, but it doesn't work. return File(ms, contentType, fileData.FileName);

Answer (score 0):

Your return type seems off. You could specify a Mime type for images, e.g. `"ìmage/jpeg"` for JPEG files.

I do have a similar code to read images previously uploaded to an Azure blobstorage. Apart from the way you load the byte array into the MemoryStream, the overall parameters of the function look the same.

Try

```
return File(ms, "image/jpeg");
```

instead.